# Eclipse Galileo - JUnit missing

Tags: eclipse, junit

Build Path > Add Library > JUnit unable to add JUnit3 or JUnit4 components.

I see such message in the .log

```
!MESSAGE No property tester contributes a property projectPersistentProperty     org.eclipse.team.core.repository to type class org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project
```

Eclipse Galileo installed by root user on Linux. 
It works well for root and for other users except this JUnit issue.

Why it lost Junit? 
(I've checked file permissions twice - all readable!)

Comment: I don't know about the JUnit issue, but if you have eGit/JGit installed, the error message you see might be this: http://code.google.com/p/egit/issues/detail?id=77 -- the bug is already closed, but I still observe it in the released version.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to [bug 239715](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=239715), triggered by [**`TypeExtensionManager.java`**](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.core.expressions/src/org/eclipse/core/internal/expressions/TypeExtensionManager.java?r1=1.16&r2=1.17), and due to some kind of plugins combination.

Could you check if your org.eclipse.core.expressions/.options file has the line

```
org.eclipse.core.expressions/debug/TypeExtensionManager=false
```

This should be enough to make that error message disappear.

That file is `<eclipse-SDK-3.5-win32>\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.core.expressions_3.4.100.v20090429-1800.jar`, and I just checked, it does contains the right option value (with latest Galileo) (are you using an older Galileo RC or Milestone release?).

Comment: No. I've investigated in depth eclipse newsgroups.
My problem appears on multiuser install of Eclipse under Linux.

When Eclipse installed from root it has no access to /opt/eclipse directory. Usually plugin checks r/o eclipse-home directory and saves config and other stuff into user-home/.eclipse. It works well but not with JUnit plugin!
This plugin requires write access to eclipse-home configuration.

Comment: @maxp interesting. If you do find the exact cause, you can post it here as an answer (and selected you own post as the official answer)

Comment: I have org.eclipse.core.expressions/debug/TypeExtensionManager=false but I still have the problem that the JUnit librarys are "not found".

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I was getting this problem this morning. A search showed that [it was possibly related to JGit/Egit](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg79873.html). After updating the EGit plugin from 0.5 to 0.6, the errors have not returned.

Comment: Strange.  I removed the egit plugin from my system (and didn't have jgit), and it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a variable junit or smtg similar to your customized one, add the junit folder to this varible, and give extension of it as junit4.8.1.jar.

I tried this and it works, but you have to delete any plugins of junit of version4 if present from plugins folder.